Can I improve my Numpy solution to an exercise?
I have been asked to use the following set of column indices:
 y = np.array([3, 0, 4, 1])
to turn into 1 all the elements in the following matrix:
x = np.zeros(shape = (4, 5)) 
that have y as starting column and rows given by the position of y. Just to be clear.
The final result has to be the following:
[[0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]      
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]  
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]  
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]

For example:
y[0] = 3,
then row 0, columns 3 and 4 need to be equal to 1.
I did it like this:
for (idx, num) in enumerate(y):         x[idx, num:] = 1
Can this result be written differently and/or improved by using other Numpy functions (for example, using vectorization)?

Lots of ways of doing this. For example, since x is basically a boolean mask, you can compute a mask and turn it into whatever type you want:
x = (np.arange(5) < y[:, None]).astype(float)

You might also use np.where to avoid the conversion:
x = np.where(np.arange(5) < y[:, None], 1.0, 0.0)


You can try np.indices like below
(np.indices(x.shape)[1]>=y[:,None]).astype(int)

which gives
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])


Please note that it is better to use astype than 1*. For 8-bit output types, one can even use np.view which is nearly free.

@JérômeRichard yes, thanks for the comment. I updated my answer.

Thank you @ThomasIsCoding! I didn't know about this method, it is very useful


If anyone wanted to do it somewhat efficiently in without numPy, it is of course also possible. Let's say we use a list-of-lists as the array type:
from itertools import repeat

mask = list(map(list.copy, repeat([0.]*cols, rows)))

Then we make a complement of the y list, to get the number of ones on the right side of each row:
yc = [cols - c for c in y]

Then we can use the side-effectful list.__setitem__ to set the desired items to 1:
any(map(list.__setitem__, 
        mask,
        map(slice, y, repeat(cols)),
        map(repeat, repeat(1.0), yc))
    )

We abuse any to iterate the map, since it outputs None each time. Not nice, but works.
The above is doing mask[y[row] : cols] = repeat(1.0, cols-y[row]).
Unfortunately, Python does not do any broadcasting with slice assignments, so we need an iterable to be the source of data, even though it's an extra layer of indirection.
Complete example:
from collections.abc import Collection
from itertools import chain, repeat


def format_matrix(l: list) -> str:
    return str(l).replace('], [', '],\n [')


def make_mask(row_indices: Collection[int], cols: int):
    rows = len(row_indices)
    mask = list(map(list.copy, repeat([0.]*cols, rows)))
    row_cindices = [cols-c for c in row_indices]
    any(map(list.__setitem__,
            mask,
            map(slice, row_indices, repeat(cols)),
            map(repeat, repeat(1.0), row_cindices))
        )
    return mask


print(format_matrix(make_mask([3, 0, 4, 1], 5)))

Output:
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
 [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
 [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]

Note: There is nothing wrong with using numPy for it, when the highest efficiency is needed. Otherwise, though, plain old Python does the job all right.

Seems not only far more complicated but also 2-4 times slower than the simple return [[0.0] * c + [1.0] * (cols-c) for c in row_indices].
